# Firebird SQL. How to allow for BOM components in SOH when calculating production requirements

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to write a query to find the purchasing/manufacturing requirements, based on our sales orders and taking into account our stock on hand and work in progress.

I am using a Firebird 2.5 server

My approach has been to begin with the sales orders, then

- use a recursive query to identify all the items that are required.
- Then to subtract those requirements from the work in progress and stock on hand to give available and free quantities.

The first part works well, but the second part fails to take into account the child components present in the stock on hand.

For example Item A includes 3 x Item B
I have sales for 5 x Item A and 2 x Item B

The query will correctly tell me that I need 5 X Item A and 17 x Item B

But if I have 2 x Item A in stock It will tell me I need 3 x Item A and 17 x Item B , not allowing for the 6 x Item B already present in the 2 x Item A

If I try to subtract the Stock On Hand, inside the recursive part of the query, it may subtract the same items several times.

I think I somehow need to use two recursive queries, but I'm not sure how.

```
    WITH RECURSIVE RPL (ITEMCODE, LINECODE, ITEMNAME, PERQTY)  AS
 (
  SELECT MAX(SALESHEADER.ORDERNUMBER), SALESLINES.LINECODE, MAX(SALESLINES.LINEDESCRIPTION), SUM(SALESLINES.ORDERQTY)
  FROM SALESHEADER, SALESLINES
  WHERE ORDERSTATUS = 'Open' 
    AND ORDERDESCRIPTION NOT SIMILAR TO '%F/C%'
    AND SALESLINES.ORDERNUMBER = SALESHEADER.ORDERNUMBER
  GROUP BY SALESLINES.LINECODE
UNION ALL
  SELECT CHILD.ITEMCODE,  CHILD.LINECODE, CHILD.LINEDESCRIPTION, CHILD.PERQTY*PARENT.PERQTY 
  FROM RPL PARENT, BOMLINES CHILD
  WHERE PARENT.LINECODE = CHILD.ITEMCODE
    AND CHILD.CODETYPE = 'Item Code'
)
SELECT RPL.LINECODE, MAX(RPL.ITEMNAME) AS DESCRIPTION , MAX(ITEMMASTER.ONHANDQTY) AS ONHAND, MAX(ITEMMASTER.SUPPLYQTY) AS SUPPLY,
       SUM(RPL.PERQTY) AS DEMAND,
       (MAX(ITEMMASTER.SUPPLYQTY) + MAX(ITEMMASTER.ONHANDQTY)) - SUM(RPL.PERQTY) AS AVAILABLE,
       MAX(ITEMMASTER.ONHANDQTY) - SUM(RPL.PERQTY) AS FREE

FROM RPL JOIN ITEMMASTER ON ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE = RPL.LINECODE
GROUP BY RPL.LINECODE;
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If item A already includes item B, why are you querying its child components? If B is part of A, then you don't need to know about those B separately.

Comment: Hi Mark. Both A and B may be used in other assemblies. Some of the Bill Of Materials explode out to 10 levels with several hundred components, and many of the components and assemblies are used in several branches.

Comment: I probably don't understand your problem. You say your problem is you don't want to count the Bs that are part of the As. So don't count them, and if you don't count them, you either don't need to query them, or you need to mark them in some way.